# is it safe to do setState for undefined values in react

Tags: reactjs

is it safe if I will do this

```
this.setState({
                    data: data
                });
```

without adding data in constructor method in react -

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data:null
        };
    }
```

Because without declaring in state also it works fine, but when I say

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data
            };
        }
```

this gives error.

If I will not add data inside state in constructor it works fine, is it safe ?

Comment: that is because only data means data:data and you don't have any variable named data in constructor

Comment: If I will not add data inside state in constructor it works fine, is it safe ?

Comment: Its really up to you or any other dev that works on the class as to if its *safe*. Is there a good reason to not initialize your data? Its only unsafe if you expect it to have a value or be an array or object, but its initialized to undefined. Like others have said, its best practice to initialize to the data structure you expect, but there's no rule that says you have to. Nothing will inherently break because you set poor initial values.

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to declare the state before using.
And here `this.state = { data };` means `this.state = { data: data }` so it will occurs `data is undefined.`

Comment: If I will not add data inside state in constructor it works fine, is it safe ? I know it's best to declare. ut still asking sorry

Answer (score 1):

This give errors because is this case `data` is not a property of state object but a variable you assign inside state object

```
 constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    data
                };
            }
```